# Unable to display buttons using slack-go Actions

Tags: go, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I am trying to display two buttons: "No thanks!" and "Yes, please!" following this [tutorial](https://blog.gopheracademy.com/advent-2017/go-slackbot/#:%7E:text=let%E2%80%99s%20retrieve%20the-,scores,-!). However, I only get the Text field in an ephemeral message instead of the title and two buttons:

```
func handleIsArticleGood() (interface{}, error) {
        attachment := slack.Attachment{
        Text:       "Would you like to see the most recent scores?",
        CallbackID: "ask_us",
        Color:      "#666666",
        Actions: []slack.AttachmentAction{
            slack.AttachmentAction{
                Name:  "action",
                Text:  "No thanks!",
                Type:  slack.ActionType("button"),
                Value: "no",
            },
            slack.AttachmentAction{
                Name:  "action",
                Text:  "Yes, please!",
                Type:  slack.ActionType("button"),
                Value: "yes",
            },
        },
    }
    return attachment, nil

}
```

I can see the actions in the response, but not the buttons:

```
socketmode: 2024/02/29 12:00:27 socket_mode_managed_conn.go:348: Sending Socket Mode response with envelope ID "$envID": &{d02eddad-fe96-4a46-8aa0-ccd6a7e4bd09 {#666666  ask_us 0         Would you like to see the most recent scores?       [] [{action No thanks!  button no  0 [] [] [] <nil> } {action Yes, please!  button yes  0 [] [] [] <nil> }] [] {[]}   }}
```

[image]

[image]

My linter also picks up the following warning (in the screenshot above as well):

`"redundant type from array, slice or map composite literal"`

FWIW, I tried setting the `Type` value to "button" as a string and setting it as a `slack.ActionType` as that seemed to be the expected value based on the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that this is, for some reason, not possible using the above implementation. Instead, I used an [example](https://github.com/slack-go/slack/blob/master/examples/buttons/buttons.go#L26) from the slack-go repository.
This function seems to handle displaying the correct buttons (though I don't appear to be getting a value back)--

```
func handleIsArticleGood(command slack.SlashCommand, client *slack.Client) error {

    attachment := slack.Attachment{
        Pretext:    "pretext",
        Fallback:   "We don't currently support your client",
        CallbackID: "accept_or_reject",
        Color:      "#3AA3E3",
        Actions: []slack.AttachmentAction{
            slack.AttachmentAction{
                Name:  "accept",
                Text:  "Accept",
                Type:  "button",
                Value: "accept",
            },
            slack.AttachmentAction{
                Name:  "reject",
                Text:  "Reject",
                Type:  "button",
                Value: "reject",
                Style: "danger",
            },
        },
    }
    _, _, err := client.PostMessage(command.ChannelID, slack.MsgOptionAttachments(attachment))
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to post message: %w", err)
    }
    return nil
}
```

[image]